# not able to convert UTC to PST and vice versa

Tags: javascript, timezone, momentjs

I am using [`momentjs#timezone`](https://momentjs.com/timezone/docs/) lib to convert into timezone from `UTC` and vice versa.

Right now, facing some issue with conversion.

Hers is my code.

```
var myDate = "2019-05-11 18:22:40" //stored in DB utc format
myDate = timezone(myDate).tz("America/Los_Angeles").format("YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss"); //converted in America/Los_Angeles Timezone
//output : myDate = "2019-05-11 05:52:40"
```

Now,want to covert into UTC again

```
myDate = timezone.tz(myDate, "America/Los_Angeles"); //added tz
myDate = timezone(myDate).tz("utc").format("YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss");
```

but the output is coming `"2019-05-11 12:52:40`" which is not same as input `"2019-05-11 18:22:40"`.

Am I doing anything wrong here?

Answer (score 2):

When you create a moment from a string and the time zone is not specified, moment assumes that it's local time. As per [the moment docs](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/):

> moment(...) is local mode. Ambiguous input (without offset) is assumed
>   to be local time. Unambiguous input (with offset) is adjusted to local
>   time.

So "2019-05-11 18:22:40" will be read by moment as a date in the local timezone.

You can have moment assume it's UTC using `moment.utc("2019-05-11 18:22:40")`.

That means changing your code like this:

```
var myDate = "2019-05-11 18:22:40" //stored in DB utc format
myDate = timezone.utc(myDate).tz("America/Los_Angeles").format("YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss");
```

But ideally your database should be storing/returning the dates using the [ISO-8601 standard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) for time display so that the timezone is clear, i.e. "2019-05-11T18:22:40Z". The "Z" indicates UTC so moment will automatically parse this as UTC if you call `moment("2019-05-11T18:22:40Z")`.

Comment: I updated answer to make the simple solution more clear. The more ideal solution means changing what the backend is returning

Comment: Did you try the code change `myDate = timezone.utc(myDate).tz("America/Los_Angeles").format("YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss");
`